# Show/Hide Text depending on a field value using Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

I am trying to hide/show text depending on other field value.

Here's the code.

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="updateCheckBoxPlan"
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
  <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.isRefreshed}" name="buttonLabel"/>
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="color:red">
        <p><b>Test</b></p>
        </div>
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:8rem">

<lightning:button
    label="Confirm Submission"
    variant="brand"
    onclick="{!c.updateCheck }"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    updateCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
        var rid = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.updateChk");
        action.setParams({key : rid});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();              
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    console.log("Unknown Error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    isRefreshed: function(component, event, helper) {
        location.reload();
    },
})
```

**Helper**

```
({
    updateCheck11_helper : function(c,e,h) {
        alert('Success!');
        var save_action = c.get("c.updateCheck");
        save_action.setParams({
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(save_action);
    }
})
```

The text *Test* should be hidden when for example Family__c is equal to "" OR blank.

[image]

Any kind of help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.force:refreshView` is an application event. It will refresh all the components which are rendered and implement handler for it. This should be used ONLY when there are no other options left. However, for your use case, you 2 options - `slds-hide` and `aura:if`.

**Option-1: Using `slds-hide`. You can use this when you need the element to be rendered in DOM but hidden from view.**

.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="updateCheckBoxPlan"
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

    <div aura:id="myDiv" class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="color:red">
        <p><b>Test</b></p>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:8rem">        
        <lightning:button label="Confirm Submission"
                          variant="brand"
                          onclick="{!c.updateCheck }"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

You should identify the target element with [aura:id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm)s as shown above.

Now in .js file:

```
updateCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
    var rid = component.get("v.recordId");
    var action = component.get("c.updateChk");
    action.setParams({key : rid});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // if( -- conditions -- )
            $A.util.addClass(component.find("myDiv","slds-hide")); // to hide
            // $A.util.removeClass(component.find("myDiv","slds-hide")); // to show 
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Unknown Error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

[addClass, removeClass & toggleClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm) are used for adding/removing/toggling the classes on target elements.

**Option-2: Using `aura:if`. You can use this when you dont want the elements to be even rendered in DOM. When they are not rendered, you cannot get the elements using component.find and aura:id.** Below is how you can implement.

.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="updateCheckBoxPlan"
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="show" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.show}">
        <div aura:id="myDiv" class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="color:red">
            <p><b>Test</b></p>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:8rem">        
        <lightning:button label="Confirm Submission"
                          variant="brand"
                          onclick="{!c.updateCheck }"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

.js file:

```
updateCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
    var rid = component.get("v.recordId");
    var action = component.get("c.updateChk");
    action.setParams({key : rid});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // if( -- conditions -- )
            component.set("v.show",true); // to hide
            // component.set("v.show",false); // to show 
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Unknown Error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: Thank you! I can now modify the IF statement in my Controller, but I have a question sorry because I'm new to coding. I would like to know on how can I get the value of the field? Assuming that the API of the field is family__c? Thanks again

Comment: It depends and actually a very broad perspective of what you are asking. There are different ways like recordEditForm or from Apex. You will be implementing in different ways. Its not clear from this question of how you are planning to implement. However, I would suggest to try these and post separate question on that.

Comment: Family__c field is just a formula field in Salesforce. I already tried your code and it's running without any errors. The field is hiding depending on the component.set value. My only concern now is getting the value of the formula field. Thanks again!

Comment: you can check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aura:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation) tag to conditionally render the parts of the view in a lightning component.

So in your case, you can create a String type aura attribute and set it to Family__c value on component load (init handler) and then use that String attribute in the aura:if tag to conditionally render the text "Test"

For instance,

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="strTest" type="String"/>

  <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.strTest))}">
    //TRUE - show your component here
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="color:red">
     <p><b>Test</b></p>
    </div>
 </aura:if> 

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to coding can you please elaborate on how would I declare an Aura:Attribute then make it value the record field value, for example: Family__c

Appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting div in `<aura:if>`
You can use the [aura:if][1] and [aura:set] to toggle

**[1]: https://www.codeinsalesforce.com/post/Aura-If-else/ - Example**

Below is the reference code

`<aura:attribute name="IsSuccessful" type="Boolean"  default="true" />

  <aura:if isTrue="{!(v.IsSuccessful == 'true')}">  'Success'
    <aura:set attribute="else">  'Unsuccessful'
    </aura:set>
  </aura:if>`